# how do i set the text of a second text view in a array adapter from a tutorial

Tags: java, android, arrays, youtube

I have recently followed a tutorial by Derek Banas on youtube on how to create a custom array adapter. In the Adapter code he had entered only one string array for one text view. I have two text views and two string arrays and i have entered the first string array for the first text view like in the video but how do i do the second?

Here is the video tutorial from Derek Banas: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rhj4_KBD6BQ&list=UUwRXb5dUK4cvsHbx-rGzSgw

Here is my Adapter Code:

```
class HangarAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {


public HangarAdapter(Context context,String[] values) {
    super(context, R.layout.hangar_layout, values);

}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    LayoutInflater theInflater = LayoutInflater.from(getContext());

    View theView = theInflater.inflate(R.layout.hangar_layout, parent, false);

    TextView TextView1 = (TextView) theView.findViewById(R.id.textView1);


    //TextView2 Is the text view i want the second string array to go into
    TextView TextView2 = (TextView) theView.findViewById(R.id.textView2);

    TextView1.setText(getItem(position));

    ImageView theImageView = (ImageView) theView.findViewById(R.id.imageView);

    return theView;
    }
```

Here is how i set the adapter in the activity:

```
    String[] ship = {"Scout Ship", "Ranger Ship" , "Gun Ship MK.1",
            "Conquerer Ship", "Gun Ship MK.2", "Tank Ship",
            "Battle Ship MK.1", "Titan Ship", "Battle Ship MK.2",
            "Colossal Titan Ship"};

    //shipDesc below is the second string array.
    String[] shipDesc = {"10 Planets Every 5 Secs \n 100$",
            "50 Planets Every 5 Secs \n 500$",
            "100 Planets Every 5 Secs \n 1500$",
            "500 Planets Every 4 Secs \n 3000$",
            "1000 Planets Every 4 Secs \n 7500$",
            "5000 Planets Every 4 Secs \n 15000$",
            "10000 Planets Every 3 Secs \n 50000$",
            "30000 Planets Every 3 Secs \n 100000$",
            "60000 Planets Every 3 Secs \n  500000$",
            "100000 Planets Every 1 Secs \n 1000000$"};

    ListView hangarList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.hangarList);
    ListAdapter adapter = new HangarAdapter(this, ship);

hangarList.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Comment: You might not be aware of this, but the way StackOverflow works is that when someone gives you the correct answer to your question, you're supposed to accept the one you think is the best answer.  This lets future readers see which answer actually solved the problem (so it guides them to the best answer), and it gives credit to the person who's spent their time helping you.  If no one answers your question correctly, it's fine to not accept any of the answers.  But you've never accepted an answer for any of your questions, so you should do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since both array have same length so make this

```
class HangarAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {

     //shipDesc below is the second string array.
        String[] shipDesc = {"10 Planets Every 5 Secs \n 100$",
                "50 Planets Every 5 Secs \n 500$",
                "100 Planets Every 5 Secs \n 1500$",
                "500 Planets Every 4 Secs \n 3000$",
                "1000 Planets Every 4 Secs \n 7500$",
                "5000 Planets Every 4 Secs \n 15000$",
                "10000 Planets Every 3 Secs \n 50000$",
                "30000 Planets Every 3 Secs \n 100000$",
                "60000 Planets Every 3 Secs \n  500000$",
                "100000 Planets Every 1 Secs \n 1000000$"};


    public HangarAdapter(Context context,String[] values) {
        super(context, R.layout.hangar_layout, values);

    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        LayoutInflater theInflater = LayoutInflater.from(getContext());

        View theView = theInflater.inflate(R.layout.hangar_layout, parent, false);

        TextView TextView1 = (TextView) theView.findViewById(R.id.textView1);


        //TextView2 Is the text view i want the second string array to go into
        TextView TextView2 = (TextView) theView.findViewById(R.id.textView2);

        TextView1.setText(getItem(position));
        TextView2.setText(shipDesc[position])

        ImageView theImageView = (ImageView) theView.findViewById(R.id.imageView);

        return theView;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using a String-array, create a ship class with a title and a description field and make a ship-array.

```
Ship ship = (Ship) getItem(position);
textview1.setText(ship.getTitle());
textView2.setText(ship.getDesc());
```